# Find the maximum value of: $\frac{x^4}{x^8+2x^6-4x^4+8x^2+16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the maximum value of: $$\cfrac{x^4}{x^8+2x^6-4x^4+8x^2+16}$$

I think this means we have to minimize the denominator. But when I am trying to do so, I'm not getting the denominator in terms of a square + constant.

I don't know calculus so please don't give a hint related to that.

I don't know how to start, so hints would be appreciated. This question was given in an exercise based on AM, GM HM inequality, but since they haven't mentioned $x$ is positive, we can't use it I think.

Thanks.

Comment: $$\frac{x^4}{x^8+2x^6-4x^4+8x^2+16}=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\dfrac4{x^2}\right)^2+2\left(x^2+\dfrac4{x^2}\right)-12}.$$

Comment: Hint: $x$ may not be positive, but what about the terms you have? Are $x^2$, $x^4$, $x^6$, $x^8$ positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing numerator and denominator by $x^4$, the expression transforms to,
$$\dfrac{1}{x^4+2x^2-4+\dfrac{8}{x^2}+\dfrac{16}{x^4}}$$
Now you can apply AM-GM on the terms $x^4,2x^2,\dfrac{8}{x^2},\dfrac{16}{x^4}$ to finish it off.

Comment: Motivation: Trying to minimize the denominator is a natural approach but you need to realize that when you choose a value of $x$ to minimize the denominator, you change the value of the numerator. In order to keep the numerator constant, we divide both by $x^4$